# How to handle inheritance on page objects

Tags: java, selenium, inheritance, automation, pageobjects

I have the following issue:

I have a home page where I load the URL with the following structure:

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    getDriver().get("URL");
}
```

Then I have another page, which extends from the HomePage:

```
public class OptionsPage extends HomePage {

public OptionsPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}
```

Now, the issue is on the test, where I want to get the OptionsPage from an action (let's say clicking a button present on HomePage). It seems that the page just loads again once I call it:

```
    // Open page
    HomePage home = getHomePage(); //loads URL from BasePage

    // click on some option which takes me to the OptionsPage
    OptionsPage options = home.clickOnRandomOption(); //this method right here loads the URL again, from there the assertion fails since the page just loads again.
    Assert.assertTrue(options.isRandomOptionSelected(), "Obviously it wasn't selected.");
```

The method to click the option on the home page looks like this:

```
public OptionsPage clickOnRandomOption() {
    getWait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(RandomOption));
    RandomOption.click();
    return new FlightOptionsPage(getDriver());
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge is that when you instantiate your `optionsPage` you're executing all constructors up the chain.

From your code structure, you're running: `OptionsPage` -> `HomePage` -> `BasePage` every time you want to create an `optionsPage`. It's the testing POM equivalent of the [Gorilla-banana-jungle](https://medium.com/codemonday/banana-gorilla-jungle-oop-5052b2e4d588) problem.

I can see that the return type from `home.clickOnRandomOption()` is an `OptionsPage` so I'm assuming that's where you instantiate the options page.

Two suggestions - either of them will fix your problem, but I recommend you think about implementing both:

- Don't chain your pages like that. Keep each one separate and ONLY extend once i.e. each page only extends from `BasePage`. If there is a common method which more than one page needs, put it in your `BasePage` and there's no need to extend page from other pages.
- Don't execute test-context-impacting code in your constructors - use contructors only for initating variables. By this, I mean that when you create your `HomePage` do not navigate (`driver.get("URL")`) in the constructor. This will cause future complications for you when you run tests. For example, what if, you wanted to start on `pageX` and navigate to home via an auto-redirect then do more actions on home? - your POM won't support it as when you create `homePage` you're going to navigate the URL to there.

Comment: Definitely it's not a good choice to chain constructors like that. What I did was, in my BaseTest class, just get the URL on a BeforeSuite method so I can get the page up and running before each test, and get that out of the HomePage. Will definitely keep an eye for that in the future and might probably put common methods in BasePage from now on. Thanks!